# How to efficiently save and load dataset with h5py?

Tags: python, numpy, h5py

I have a dataset of size `(900, 200, 308, 311, 1)`, where in each sample, there are `200` images, each of dimension `308x311`. I have created an `h5py` file (dtype: `float`) out of this dataset, which comes out to be around `125GB` (much larger than the actual data).

The data creation process itself took a lot of time. This is how I have done it:

```
input = []
# 900 samples
for sample in dataset:
    sequence = []
    # 200 images/sample
    for file in images:
        img = #read file
        sequence.append(img)
    input.append(sequence)
input = np.array(input).reshape(900, 200, 308, 311, 1)

with h5py.File('X.h5py', 'w') as f:
    d = f.create_dataset('X', data=input, dtype='float')
```

When I load this file, it again takes forever to load the data in memory

```
f = h5py.File("X.h5py","r")
X = np.array(f['X'])
```

Is there an efficient way to store and load data this big. I have seen `chunking` the data, but I am unsure if doing that can help. Also, if I store the data in chunks, can I load one sample from the data instead of chunks like before?

Comment: You **DON'T** want to do this: `X = np.array(f['X'])` (unless you have to). You are reading the entire `X` dataset into an array. You can use numpy slicing to get a subset of the data (1 image at at time). If I understand your data layout, you can slice 1 image from 1 sample like this: image_data = np.array(f['X'][sample#, image#, :, :, :])

Comment: Why are you using float dtype? Typically images use 8-bit UInts, which would be much smaller than float.  And are these images in color? If so I would expect another dimension of size 3? What format are the images? I/O is probably the primary source of slowness, do anything you can do to make the data smaller will help with speed.

Comment: @kcw78 Thank you, I will try this. What if I want to have a stream of data e.g PyTorch's dataloader?

Comment: @farenorth The images are 16-bit gray valued. The reason I am storing in float is because of normalization.

Comment: I haven't used PyTorch, so I can't help with that question. Also, you don't need `np.array()` above. This is sufficient to get a NumPy array: `image_data = f['X'][sample#, image#, :, :, :] `

Comment: How is your access pattern. eg. do you iterate over all images, parts of the images,...

Comment: @hash_ir float16 dtype might be helpful?  http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/whatsnew/2.2.html#mini-float-support-issue-141

Comment: I resolved the problem. Check my answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things I did which resulted in faster storing and loading

1. Instead of appending the image as a matrix, I used a flattened vector.
2. I normalized the data in a way that I don't have to use `float` anymore.

These two things led to saving the data in dimensions of `(#samples, #time_steps, #pixels)`. Then I reshaped the numpy array after loading the `h5py` file.

**Result:** Less memory consumption and faster access time.

Thanks @kcw8 for the mentioning the slicing. It also helped when I want to generate a subset of the data without loading the entire dataset.